# PostgreSQL: ошибка при удалении индекса

Tags: postgresql, index

Создал индекс для таблицы

```
demo=# CREATE INDEX ON ticket_flights(fare_conditions); CREATE INDEX
```

Спустя какое-то время понял, что нужно кое-что переделать и удалить сам индекс. Однако....

```
demo=# DROP INDEX ticket_flights;
ОШИБКА:  "ticket_flights" - это не индекс
ПОДСКАЗКА:  Выполните DROP TABLE для удаления таблицы.
```

Я понял, что в самой записи индекса есть ошибка (я не дал ему названия, а сразу таблицу включил), однако в пособии был похожий пример, где говорилось что такое допустимо...Тем более, раз индекс создан, а работа по моим запросам стала вестись быстрее, то он явно рабочий. Сама подсказка меня настораживает. Скажите, пожалуйста, что нужно предпринять для исправления данной ошибки.

Comment: Если имя опущено, PostgreSQL формирует подходящее имя по имени родительской таблицы и именам индексируемых столбцов.

Comment: SELECT * FROM pg_indexes WHERE tablename = 'your_table';

Comment: Спасибо, всё получилось. Буду знать.